# Faster method to write items to mariadb other than jpaitemwriter

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-batch, itemwriter

I have a batch job that reads from and Oracle database, stores JPA with JPA ITEM READER and writes to MariaDB with JPA ITEM WRITER. Is there a way to do bulk insert into MariaDB or a bulk execute the way mongodb has bulkoperations.execute() method?

I've used the provided JpaItemWriter as Follows:

```
@Bean
@Transactional
public JpaItemWriter<entity.maria.class> classJpaItemWriter() {
    JpaItemWriter<entity.maria.class> writer = new JpaItemWriter<>();
    writer.setEntityManagerFactory(mariaEntityManager.getObject());

    return writer;
}
```

The Reader is :

```
public JpaPagingItemReader<PojoClass> classJpaReader() throws Exception {

    String jpqlQuery = "SELECT t FROM PojoClass t where rownum < 15001";
    JpaPagingItemReader<PojoClass> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
    reader.setQueryString(jpqlQuery);
    reader.setEntityManagerFactory(oracleEntityManager.getObject());
    reader.setPageSize(100000);
    reader.afterPropertiesSet();
    reader.setSaveState(true);
    return reader;
}
```

The Step Configuration is:

```
@Bean
public Step classStep() throws Exception {
    Step auditStep = stepBuilderFactory.get(
            "entity.oracle.PojoClass").<class, entity.maria.class>chunk(
            10000)
            .reader(classJpaReader())
            .writer(classJpaItemWriter())
            .transactionManager(mariaTransactionManager)
            .listener(auditWriterListener())
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipLimit(10000)
            .skip(Exception.class)
            .build();
    return auditStep;
}
```

I would like to do a custom writer that would bulk insert values into mariaDb and would like the time for insert/upsert to decrease. Currently the time taken for insertion of 15000 is 326 seconds...This seems kind of lengthy.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` which uses `JdbcTemplate#batchUpdate` behind the scene. This is usually faster the JPA item writers as it does not interact with a persistent context, first/second level cache, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will this also handle duplicate ids the way the oracleentity manager does within the jpaitemwriter?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point. If you insert an item with a duplicate Id, you will get an exception, just like the `JpaItemWriter`.